# drupal template.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

how should i know which variables and objects can be used directly in this file.(eg:$node,$term....) thank you.

Comment: For Drupal question there is drupal.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In template.php**

```
/**
 * Override or insert PHPTemplate variables into the templates.
 */
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  _vdump(get_defined_vars(), 1);
}

/**
 * Override or insert PHPTemplate variables into the templates.
 */
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  _vdump(get_defined_vars(), 1);
}
```

**And add dump function to custom module**

```
/*
 * Custom dump function
 *
 * @param $vars
 *   An string or array containing the data.
 * @param $keys
 *   If true6 function will return keys of $vars array
 * @return a dump of $vars as drupal message.
 */
function _vdump($var, $keys = FALSE) {
  if($keys){
    drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r(array_keys($var), 1) . '</pre>');
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($var, 1) . '</pre>');
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i don't know on which page i can see the output result.

Comment: you can see result on any page

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're talking about creating/modifying a theme. You could use most of the [standard Drupal globals](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals/6). You can always use [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) to see if any other variables have been defined.

Comment: thank you. could i use the $term ,$node object in the  template.php

Comment: I don't think so. I think you should be using a [page.tpl.php](http://drupal.org/node/11812) or [node.tpl.php](http://drupal.org/node/11816)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such variables in the template.php file.
Do you think of `$node`, `$terms`, ... that you find on page.tpl.php or node.tpl.php ?

If yes, those variables are generated in the [preprocess](http://drupal.org/node/223430) functions.

Modules can implements those hook to define new variables that you can directly use in those file, or template.php can also define some new variables.

Please have a look in the documentation about the [preprocess](http://drupal.org/node/223430)

Comment: this code is from someone in template.php:function garland_separate_terms($node_taxonomy) {
   if ($node_taxonomy) {
foreach ($node_taxonomy AS $term) {
 $links[$term->vid]['taxonomy_term_'. $term->tid] ....

why he can use the $term object directly.